# ckan datapusher fails to read json header and types

Tags: ckan

Ubuntu 14.01 / CKAN 2.3 installed from source. UTF-8.

Datapusher can't determine headers and types when uploading json to DataStore.
Top of file I'm trying to upload/update (As shown from text view i CKAN):

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "baal_og_grillpladser.2",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          10.3591,
          55.407
        ]
      },
      "geometry_name": "wkb_geometry",
      "properties": {
        "navn": "Åløkkeskoven ved den gamle golfbane ",
        "beskrivelse": "Bål- og grillplads på græsarealer ved Åløkkeskoven tæt på Søhusstien. Her er også en lille overdækning hvor man kan søge ly, og der er en balancebane og en legeplads tæt på. I perioden 1. maj til 1. oktober lægges der brænde ud før weekender og helligdag",
        "lat": 55.407,
        "long": 10.3591
      }
    },
```

From the datapusher.error.log:

```
[Wed Apr 22 17:05:46.381327 2015] [:error] [pid 22029:tid 140315638884096] Fetching from: (local)/dataset/98fc8c64-6dfb-4602-98fc-1f9b2ff56bab/resource/83a01e3f-38dc-4c05-9d97-9ba1c1a594a5/download/CUsersljiDesktopbalpladser.json
[Wed Apr 22 17:05:46.744956 2015] [:error] [pid 22029:tid 140315638884096] Deleting "83a01e3f-38dc-4c05-9d97-9ba1c1a594a5" from datastore.
[Wed Apr 22 17:05:46.782179 2015] [:error] [pid 22029:tid 140315638884096] Determined headers and types: []
[Wed Apr 22 17:05:46.880928 2015] [:error] [pid 22029:tid 140315638884096] Successfully pushed 0 entries to "83a01e3f-38dc-4c05-9d97-9ba1c1a594a5".
[Wed Apr 22 17:05:51.055612 2015] [:error] [pid 22029:tid 140315919210240] Fetching from: (local)/dataset/98fc8c64-6dfb-4602-98fc-1f9b2ff56bab/resource/83a01e3f-38dc-4c05-9d97-9ba1c1a594a5/download/CUsersljiDesktopbalpladser.json
[Wed Apr 22 17:05:51.367964 2015] [:error] [pid 22029:tid 140315919210240] Deleting "83a01e3f-38dc-4c05-9d97-9ba1c1a594a5" from datastore.
[Wed Apr 22 17:05:51.512404 2015] [:error] [pid 22029:tid 140315919210240] Determined headers and types: []
[Wed Apr 22 17:05:51.614173 2015] [:error] [pid 22029:tid 140315919210240] Successfully pushed 0 entries to "83a01e3f-38dc-4c05-9d97-9ba1c1a594a5".
[Wed Apr 22 17:06:00.024942 2015] [:error] [pid 22029:tid 140315919210240] Fetching from: (local)/dataset/98fc8c64-6dfb-4602-98fc-1f9b2ff56bab/resource/83a01e3f-38dc-4c05-9d97-9ba1c1a594a5/download/CUsersljiDesktopbalpladser.json
[Wed Apr 22 17:06:00.260876 2015] [:error] [pid 22029:tid 140315919210240] Deleting "83a01e3f-38dc-4c05-9d97-9ba1c1a594a5" from datastore.
[Wed Apr 22 17:06:00.301750 2015] [:error] [pid 22029:tid 140315919210240] Determined headers and types: []
[Wed Apr 22 17:06:00.393785 2015] [:error] [pid 22029:tid 140315919210240] Successfully pushed 0 entries to "83a01e3f-38dc-4c05-9d97-9ba1c1a594a5".
```

(local) replaces local http source
json source has been verified using codebeautify.org jsonvalidate
Datapusher manage to detect headers and types for text files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DataPusher will only recognize tabular formats like CSV or Excel, not JSON files

Comment: Hi @amercader, say I want to update file with JSON format to datastore, I would need to do it manually? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you would use the [datastore_create](https://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/datastore.html#ckanext.datastore.logic.action.datastore_create) action to push your data against an existing or new resource